# Is there a design pattern for this...?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

When a user selects a record in a datagrid I launch a pop-up window with more detailed info. The user can make changes to the record in this window but they don't have to save them. For example, they can click the X to close the window.

Unfortunately, I am stupid and whenever a user makes changes I update the object directly.

Is there a pattern for copying the object and then mapping the changes to it when a user confirms they want to save?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't go with copy and merge. Why don't you just update the object only if the user explicitly wants to update/save? Let the UI be UI and condense the relevant information from it as soon as you need it.
Another way that may be appliable, if you want something like temporary edits, would be using commands for every atomic update, where every command has an inverse - undo - command. If you keep these in a history, you could just go back to the initial state.

Comment: Where do I store the edits until I know when the user explicitly wants to update/save?

Comment: I was going to say something along similar lines, use the command pattern with the momento pattern. The momento saves the state, which then can be rolled back to (undo).

Comment: @fumeng: I guess you mean the second approach with the commands? I'd use a history for that which is basically a list of the commands that have been executed. The actions in the UI would result in the addition of commands to the history and executing them. Therefore you need a way to wrap any possible edit into a common interface. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#Structure) for an example. So there is quite a bit of an overhead with that.

Comment: Hmm, I may stick with the simpler solution which is what you first explained; only update the object when the user clicks 'save'. At that point, go to each of my components and grab the values I need to properly update the object. I realize that assigning the values to the object as soon as a user interacts with them is premature and just plain wrong.

Comment: I'm realizing that I don't need undo functionality. All I need is to either keep all the edits the user made or forget them all. So I'll forego the Command and Memento patterns because there'd be too much and stick with this. Thank you for your input.

Comment: MPO is that you just need to populate your Popup with the VO, and use one way binding (so the View is initially populated by its values, but the View doesn't update the VO at all).  Then, when you close the window, if you save the changes, dispatch an event that contains the values from the View.  Somewhere else in your app (preferably in a controller), transfer the values from the event to the VO.